# How can bind Ctrl+m keybinding to Enter using Keyboard Maestro on macOS

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

If possible, I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> keybinding to <kbd>Enter</kbd> using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/). How can I achieve this?

Related: https://superuser.com/q/55954/723632

Comment: `Ctrl-M` is already assigned to “Carriage Return” which is what `Enter` does. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: For example in safari when I type a search string andI press `Ctrl-M` , `Enter` is not applied, this occurs for other browsers and applications as well

Comment: Ah, you want to type CTRL-M and have the computer handle it as Enter?

Comment: @nohillside Yes sir! Sorry it wasn't clear in the question

Comment: Is your `Return`/`Enter` key not functioning?    Finder doesn't listen for these [ANSI/Unicode escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) because these "keyboard shortcuts" are made available for app developers.  Maybe a remap of your CR key is in order?

Comment: My `Enter` key does not work as alternative I was using `Ctrl+m` , it works in terminal like iTerm2 but does not work all over the system as Return key.

Comment: That’s the expected behavior.

Comment: I know that's why I wanted to use `keyboardmastro` (not sure is it capable or not tho) instead of https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org

Comment: Did you check whether KM allows for CTRL-M as a trigger?

Comment: karabiner does but does it freezes typing once in a while that's why I was in search for an alternative solution. I believe KM does but I was not able to figure out how that's why I asked the question

Comment: As I said, create a macro with Ctrl-M as the hot key trigger.

Comment: What will be the corresponding action in the macro for `Enter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this in detail, but the following Keyboard Maestro macro should do the job.

[image]

Comment: Works! (Tested)

Comment: Works on my end too thanks! You opened the magical box to do all kinds of bindings